# PHP: Passing Variables from an include file

Tags: php, include

I have a script where I'm trying to assign an Array values from an include file (because these same variables will be used in several scripts).

It seems to almost work, but when I try to print the variables, I get a different result:

script.php:

```
   <?php
    include("test_includes.inc.php");

     $these_numbers = $numbers;
     echo " <pre> print_r($these_numbers)   var_dump($these_numbers)
     </pre>           
     $these_numbers[0]<br>$these_numbers[1]";
    ?>
```

and test_includes.inc.php

```
   <?php
   $numbers = ARRAY('one','two');
   ?>
```

The result:

```
   print_r(Array)

   var_dump(Array)

   one
   two
```

I guess I don't understand why the print_r() and var_dump() aren't working and if this is the cause of my problems in my real script (where I do a foreach over each element in the array and run a sql query using it).

Thanks,
Tev

Comment: Uuughhhhh. Sorry - I can't believe I missed the quotes!!! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP doesn't execute function which are in double quotes. It DOES parse variables though (hence the `ARRAY`).

So:

```
$test = 'something';

echo "$test"; // outputs something

echo "strtoupper($test)"; // outputs strtoupper(something) instead of SOMETHING
```

In you specific case you can do:

```
<?php
include("test_includes.inc.php");

$these_numbers = $numbers; // not really needed, but hard to tell without seeing your complete code
echo "<pre>";var_dump($these_numbers);echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: I am wondering, doesn't `var_dump()` write directly to the output (like echo does)? Then you should do `echo " <pre>"; var_dump($these_numbers); echo "</pre>";`, shouldn't you?

Comment: And perhaps `htmlentities()`as well?

Comment: @nalply 1. You are right. Thanks - fixed 2. What does `htmlentities()` add. If anything it should be `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't interpolate function calls - it's literally outputting `print_r(`, then `$numbers`, then `)`

What you want to do is this:

```
echo " <pre> " .
     print_r($these_numbers) .  
     var_dump($these_numbers) .
     "</pre>" .        
     "$these_numbers[0]<br>$these_numbers[1]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because thouse functions don't work in quotes:

```
echo "<pre>".
     print_r($these_numbers) .
     var_dump($these_numbers) .
     "</pre>" .           
     "$these_numbers[0]<br>$these_numbers[1]";
```